# Restart Node.js server programmatically

Tags: node.js

How to restart Node.js server from code? For example, if using expressjs framework,

```
app.get('/restart', function (req, res, next) {
//Code to restart a server
})
```

I want to restart server from app like this, without going to console etc. How to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use `forever` in order to start and monitoring application.
So the restart function like this:

```
app.get('/restart', function (req, res, next) {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

After the shutdown of server, `forever` will restart service.

console:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Forever restarting script for 2 time
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
```

Comment: But who will monitor and restart `forever` itself in case it crashes or hangs?

Answer (score 1):

By combining [`npm restart`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/restart) and [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) it appears possible to restart the server programmatically. And since it allows for several scripts to be run for stopping, restarting, and starting this option would work even for multi-process servers or otherwise complex servers where simply calling `process.exit()` isn't viable.

Comment: an example would be great and allow future reader to better understand your answer

Comment: Any example of how would that work? The point of `child_process` is that it's a child process and shutting down the parent process will also shut down the child process, so you can't have the child process boot back up the parent process.

Comment: @undefined You can mark a child-process as [detached](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) which I believe makes it survive past the parent's destruction. So if you use that, with a "sleep" command at the start of the command (in case concurrent running is an issue), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a child-process as [detached](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) which I believe makes it survive past the parent's destruction. So if you use that, with a "sleep" command at the start of the command (in case concurrent running is an issue), it should work.

So presumably something like this (untested):

```
const newProcessInstance = spawn(process.argv[0], process.argv.slice(1), {
  detached: true,
  stdio: 'ignore', // not sure if this is needed
});
```