# Automatically restart a Node.Js app

Tags: linux, node.js, cron

My Node.Js app sometimes goes down (I'm working on solving the issue) but in the meanwhile I have a script (default one from WebFaction hosting), which is supposed to restart my app if it's not running.

However, it simply doesn't work (I get 502 page instead, which is also shown when I manually stop the app). I mean the app starts fine with the script, but then when the app crashes, it doesn't restart it, even though that script below runs on cron every 5 mins:

```
*/5 * * * * ~/webapps/infranodus/bin/start
```

Do you know what the problem could be and how I could solve it?

Here's the script below:

`#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/run
pid=$(/sbin/pidof /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/node)
if echo "$pid" | grep -q " "; then
  pid=""
fi
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
  user=$(ps -p $pid -o user | tail -n 1)
  if [ $user = "noduslabs" ]; then
    exit 0
  fi
fi
nohup /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/node /home/noduslabs/webapps/infra$
/sbin/pidof /home/noduslabs/webapps/infranodus/bin/node > /home/noduslabs/webap$`

PS Another thing is that when the app is crashed, I have to log in my hosting via ssh, start the app with `node app` then exit it and only then start really works. So it looks like the script actually doesn't detect the fact that the script is down that's why it probably doesn't work...

Comment: There are many tools to do that (like "forever"). Did you search ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-its-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766259/restart-node-js-server-programmatically

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu I recommend you to take a look to Upstart (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever)

```
[sudo] npm install -g forever
```

And then, start your app with forever:

```
forever start app.js
```

Your script will restart upon crashing/exiting, you can run multiple node.js applications using forever.

To stop/restart your application manually you can use:

```
forever restart [id]
forever stop [id]
```

Also, forever will store your application's logs in ~/.forever. You can easily read your application's logs using:

```
forever logs # list all logs
forever logs [id] # Tails the logs of id
```

[forever at npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever)

Comment: Thank you! And if the app crashes does forever store the log somewhere?

Comment: Yes, forever stores it's logs in a folder like ~/.forever/, forever will tell you what file it's storing the logs in when you start an application or use `forever list`