# How can I restart a node process once it reaches a certain memory size (leak)?

Tags: node.js, memory, heroku, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in a Node.js, and I'm working on trying to find it but it's currently deployed to Heroku. I'd like to currently have something that would restart the process once it reaches a certain size in memory (especially since I have a few dynos running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not finding a solution I created a npm utli lib that does that. Please note it does not work on windows though.

It's based on cluster and status npm libs.

http://github.com/DoryZi/memory_limiter

Comment: I'm curious why this got down-voted..at least explain, I am sharing this code and question to help other people that get stuck on the same issue..not because I needed an answer, as I already solved it for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use PM2 to run your app? If yes there's a good config option that fits your need called `max_memory_restart`.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/#max-memory-restart

Comment: i am using this same feature in my config file. but it is not applied. I give a limit of 50M. when check the status, it is already gone to 90 plus MBs. can u please explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Heroku will restart your Dyno if it exceeds the memory limits. This will happen automatically, so you don't really need to worry about it.

One thing you might want to try doing to help you debug it in production, however, is use the [NewRelic addon](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic?utm_campaign=newrelic&utm_medium=alert&utm_source=addons).

They give you a nice dashboard you can use to view memory usage, find bottlenecks, etc. It's really quite useful, and only takes a minute to setup (no code changes needed).

Comment: I've been using NewRelic, but it seems that heroku doesn't always restart, furthermore, when you reach maximum memory the whole app slows down to a grinding halt, so it's worthwhile to restart the app before hand, this way you ensure if you have multiple dynos it will run smoothly..

Comment: furthermore you might have lots of swaps as you reach the high memory usage

The maximum amount of RAM available to your application depends on the dyno size you use. The dyno manager will restart your dyno and log an R15 error if the memory usage of a:
1X dyno reaches 2.5GB, five times its quota.
2X dyno reaches 5GB, five times its quota.
PX dyno reaches 12GB, two times its quota.
Using a dyno size that is too small might cause constant memory swapping, which will degrade application performance.

Comment: This is correct, I left it out of my answer so as to not confuse anyone. But basically Heroku allows you to go OVER your quota by 2.5x, forcing you to use swap, before restarting your dyno. This is, in almost all cases, exactly what you want. EG: You don't want to drop user requests, it's better to simply slow them down a bit. Once the dyno restarts, everything will be reset back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Node Application Metrics ('[appmetrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics)') module.

This provides an API to register callbacks for monitoring events, including both memory usage on the process and GC heap memory usage.

The following shows you how to register callbacks for each and set up a threshold to take action on:

```
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
var monitor = appmetrics.monitor();

var THRESHOLD = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

monitor.on('memory', function(memory) {
    if (memory.physical > THRESHOLD) {
        console.log('Process physical memory usage > ' + THRESHOLD);
    }
});

monitor.on('gc', function(gc) {
    if (gc.used > THRESHOLD) {
        console.log('Garbage collected used heap > ' + THRESHOLD);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to stop the server (with the forever library for restarting [Restart Node.js server programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766259/restart-node-js-server-programmatically)):

```
        try {
    if (postRequest.length % 5 == 0) {
        const used = (process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024);
        const mem = Math.round(used * 100) / 100;
        if (mem >= 1024) { 
           //if(global.gc) global.gc(); 
           process.exit();}
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("`Failed to exit`");
    }
```