# Check if server is running and restart it

Tags: node.js, cron

I run a NodeJS server on a cloud Virtual Private Server. Sometimes I have a coding error and now Node exits the process and my website becomes unavailable. I would like to restart it automatically as soon as possible.

One option is `forever` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766259/restart-node-js-server-programmatically)), but then I can't monitor if `forever` itself is running. (Also, it didn't run the server when I tried it.)

I tried `cron` checking every minute and restarting it, but it also fails and I don't understand why. Here is the cron task:

```
* * * * * running=$(lsof -i :8443); [[ "" == "$running" ]] && /opt/bitnami/node/bin/node app.js  >> /path/to/stdout/log 2>> /path/to/stderr/log &
```

How can I restart the server soon after it hangs?

Comment: Instead of this, which is going to be a hack at best, why not [`pm2`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io) if not a proper `systemd` stub?

Comment: xy, *Sometimes I have a coding error*, that should be fixed, if your developing on it then use nodemon to restart your code after changes are done

Comment: I installed it and started NodeJS with it, it seems to work. Can you please write an answer for me to accept, and I'll ask another question in case I have any issues?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, I do fix the coding error. These errors are users hitting rare corner cases that I didn't think of. But even then, I want the other users to access the website while I understand the issue and fix the code. And by the time they get to the same corner case, it will have been fixed.